# Is it possible to prevent empty action text entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6, actiontext

I have a very simple action text model and form

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord 
  validates :title, presence: true
  has_rich_text :content
end

<%= form_with model: @course do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.rich_text_area :content %>
<% end %>
```

It's all working great but since the `content` field is optional is it possible to create a `course` model without creating `action_text_rich_texts` entries that are empty/blank? Even if the user only enters the `title` without any `content` it's currently creating them and there's a lot of unnecessary and empty `action_text_rich_texts` rows in the database

Answer (score 2):

The way I handled this in my application is with a `before_save` callback that removes the `ActionText::RichText` database record if the `body` is blank.

This avoids polluting the controller and works on both create and update actions. The `body` attribute of the `action_text` attribute is still accessible even without a corresponding database record, because ActionText will instantiate a new object if the record cannot be found (which allows you to test for `blank?` in either scenario).

Try this:

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord 
  validates :title, presence: true
  has_rich_text :content
  before_save :clean_up_content

  private

  def clean_up_content
    self.content.destroy if self.content.body.blank?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about anything built into Actiontext for this, but I would imagine you could handle this at the controller level.

The first thing I would try is to see if not setting anything to `content` prevents Rails from creating an associated record:

```rb
class CourseController
  def create
    # remove course_params[:content] if it's blank
    course_values = course_params[:content].blank? ? course_params.except(:content) : course_params

    Course.create(course_values)
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: that works when creating a course without a content, *but* if a course already had a content and it is erased on an update it does not erase the content

Answer (score 0):

Extending [Eric Powell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4072663/eric-powell)'s approach:

```rb
# app/models/concerns/do_not_save_blank_rich_text.rb

module DoNotSaveBlankRichText
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_validation :do_not_save_blank_rich_text
  end

  private

  def do_not_save_blank_rich_text
    rich_text_attributes = self.class.reflections.values.select do |reflection|
      reflection.options[:class_name] == "ActionText::RichText"
    end.map(&:name)
    rich_text_attributes.each do |rich_text_attribute|
      if self.public_send(rich_text_attribute) && self.public_send(rich_text_attribute).body.blank?
        self.public_send(rich_text_attribute).mark_for_destruction
      end
    end
  end
end
```